# How do I change the HTTP headers of a node-soap server response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, node-soap

In a [node-soap server](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap), how do I change the HTTP headers of a node-soap server response?

In a client request, I can add extra HTTP headers like so

```
client.addHttpHeader('User-Agent', `CustomUserAgent`);
```

However, what I need is to change the HTTP headers of a response. How can I do that? A way to access the http.ServerResponse object would allow me to use [setHeader](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) and would probably work for me as well.

Comment: Use express and write a middleware module for it.

Comment: @Quentin Could you please elaborate? Are you suggesting that I should use express as a base server for node-soap instead of the built-in HTTP server, and then write an express middleware to change the HTTP headers of the response?

Comment: to see an example of what @Quentin did suggest, take a look at https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soaplistenserver-path-services-wsdl---create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services